# How can I draw a histogram in C similar to normal distribution?

Tags: c

The code below is actually how I achieve the array that I need to use to draw the histogram graph similar to normal distribution but I could not find any solution for this problem except C++ solution of it. So, how can I draw the histogram graph of the array that I get from the function below by using "*" symbol to draw the histogram?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
void RandomNumGenerate(int numberArray[6],int sumOfNumbers[6][1]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int numbers[6];
    int sumOfNumbers[6][1];
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=6; i++){
        numbers[i] = i;
        sumOfNumbers[i][1] = 0;
    }
    RandomNumGenerate(numbers,sumOfNumbers);
    for(i=1; i<=6; i++){
        printf("%d\n",sumOfNumbers[i][1]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
void RandomNumGenerate(int numberArray[6],int sumOfNumbers[6][1]){
    int i,j,num;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<10000; i++){
        num = rand()%6+1;
        for(j=1; j<=6; j++){
            if(numberArray[j] == num){
                sumOfNumbers[j][1] += 1;
            }
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What is wrong with your program? Do you get an error? Unexpected output? Missing parts? Show an example of the output you want to get. There are errors in your program. In C, the array index starts with 0, not with 1. When you have `int numbers[6];`, the loop `for(i=1; i<=6; i++){ numbers[i] = i; ...` will leave the first element `numbers[0]`uninitialized and writes to the memory after the last element `numbers[5]` when `i` is 6 which is undefined behavior. The program may have unexpected behavior or may crash.

Comment: In the same way as mentioned by Bodo, `sumOfNumbers[j][1]` is also wrong as maximum index is `sumOfNumbers[j][0]`